# How to reset a scene in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, reset

I am using `cocos2d` to create a simple arrow shooting game.On reset button I am replacing the scene to The same play scene i.e i am loading the images again and again on reset button. But this is not the optimized way to do. Can somebody help me or give me an Idea to reset the game without loading the images again and again.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that you are loading this textures into memory every time? if so, retain your textures before restart to be sure that it is not unloaded from CCTextureCache. loading textures into memory is the longest process.

Comment: you can mark answer as correct to help other people find it later